# Get contents of div up to a certain point

Tags: php

I'm grabbing all the paragraph tags using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) with the following code:

```
// Product Description
$html = file_get_html('http://domain.local/index.html');
$contents = strip_tags($html->find('div[class=product-details] p'));
```

How can I say grab X amount of paragraphs until it hits the first `ul`?

```
<p>
  Paragraph 1
</p>
<p>
  Paragraph 2
</p>
<p>
  Paragraph 3
</p>
<ul>
  <li>
    List item 1
  </li>
  <li>
    List item 2
  </li>  
</ul>
<blockquote>
  Quote 1
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
  Quote 2
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
  Quote 3
</blockquote>
<p>
  Paragraph 4
</p>
<p>
  Paragraph 5
</p>
```

Comment: how about using `substr()` and `strpos()` on the content?

Comment: @nandal How so? Just to note the amount of paragraphs is variable.

Comment: can you paste the url?

Comment: @nandal It's a local site sorry, I would otherwise

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code as per requirements mentioned:-

```
<?php

$html = file_get_html('http://domain.local/index.html');
$detailTags =  $html->find('div[class=product-details] *');
$contents = "";
foreach ($detailTags as $detailTag){
    // these condition will check if tag is not <p> or it's <ul> to break the loop. 
    if (strpos($detailTag, '<ul>') === 0 && strpos($detailTag, '<p>') !== 0) {
        break;
    }
    $contents .= strip_tags($detailTag);
}
// contents will contain the output required.
echo $contents;

?>
```

OUTPUT:-

```
  Paragraph 1    Paragraph 2    Paragraph 3
```

Comment: As another fallback, can I break it if it hits a `<blockquote>` as well like this `if (strpos($detailTag, '<ul>') === 0 && strpos($detailTag, '<p>') !== 0 && strpos($detailTag, '<blockquote>') === 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Nandal's code will work for you because it will not force you to change the library.

If you don't want to be dependent upon 3rd party library then you can use PHP's `DOM Document` feature for which you would need to enable the extension.

You can look into the below code which prints the paragraphs until you hit any other tag:

```
<?php

$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML("<html><body><p>Paragraph 1</p><p>  Paragraph 2</p><p>  Paragraph 3</p><ul> <li>    List item 1  </li>  <li>    List item 2  </li>  </ul><blockquote>  Quote 1</blockquote><blockquote>  Quote 2</blockquote><blockquote>  Quote 3</blockquote><p> Paragraph 4</p><p>  Paragraph 5</p></body></html>");


$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$nodes = $xpath->query('/html/body//*');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    if($node->nodeName != "p") {
        break;
    }
    print $node -> nodeValue . "\n";
}
```